# Are analytic solutions for the Navier-Stokes equations sufficient?

Tags: real-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, mp.mathematical-physics, analytic-functions, navier-stokes

Generally, we ask for solutions of the Navier-Stokes equations, when the starting conditions are in the [Schwartz space](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space).

However, I am wondering, whether it is possible to consider just analytic starting conditions as starting condition and do some limit argument to treat all functions in the Schwartz space.

Is such a thing possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "treat all functions"? And what issue are you interested in treating? Not the millennium problem, Shirley?

Comment: Generally, in most cases, one does not limit itself to just analytic starting conditions to study the long-term behavior of them. The question is whether we can infer significant information by just looking at analytic starting conditions.